# Can I create my own good reading in µA?

Tags: current, multimeter

This multimeter is in between a Rpi0 3.3V pin and a BME280 sensor VCC.
Most of the time the sensor is sleeping.
You can see on the picture, the reading is 620µA, which seems high. Now if I use the range mA the reading is around 0.16mA.
From this question ([A really basic question about ammeters and their ranges](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/470298/a-really-basic-question-about-ammeters-and-their-ranges?newreg=41e0fc738a304ea4bb9605f61188a6c3)) should I conclude to not use the µA range from this multimeter? Or is there a way to mitigate the shunt knowing both range reading?

[image: multimeter reading]

[image: multimeter datasheet]

Edit 2 sensor datasheet:
[image: sensor datasheet]

Edit 3 circuit:
Black Crocodile to COM and red crocodile to INPUT of multimeter. The red wire doing an arc above the Raspberry pi 0 was not plugged to the 3.3V pin at the time of the picture.
[image: circuit]

Comment: Can you put a large plastic RF cap across the meter. And repeat measurments?

Comment: I have 0.1µF around, I guess not large enough. I can find bigger. What do you mean by 'across the meter'?

Comment: Schematic and data sheets required.

Comment: If you're worried about the burden of the ammeter, you might trust the higher scale reading more than the more sensitive scale reading - even though % error is larger.

Comment: 0.1 & 0.01 uF in parallel.

Comment: What sensor settings are you using? Can you check the meter calibration by measuring current through a known resistance?.

Comment: I had a 104 cap before but my wiring must have been wrong. I carefully rewired with  a cap in // and now the reading is 0.02mA. When I try to lower the range in the uA I then get 0.2uA. The order in between the range is 100 times. Great idea to measure current through a know resistance.  Should I make an edit and add a picture of the working wiring?

Comment: I added the picture of the circuit since I am not sure now that the current I am measuring is the current flowing into the sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The numbers you are seeing on the meter may be just the result of its inherent inaccuracy. The meter error is specified as \$\pm(1.0\% + 7)\$, where the "7" means a count of 7 in the least-significant digit.

If you are on the \$400\,\mu\text{A}\$ range the meter's accuracy is \$\pm 4.7\mu\text{A}\$. The error increases by a factor of ten as you increase the range by a factor of ten. On the \$40\,\text{mA}\$ range the error is \$\pm 0.47\,\text{mA}\$.

I think your measurements are just noise on the \$\text{mA}\$ range. If you are measuring \$620\mu\text{A}\$ then you must be on the \$4000\,\mu\text{A}\$ range, and the inaccuracy of that value is \$\pm 47\mu\text{A}\$.

Comment: I guess I will have to learn where this multimeter has a reading I can trust and find a good multimeter for mA/v and uA/V.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the resistance that the meter has when used as an ammeter for very low currents.  Most multimeters don’t behave like an ideal ammeter ( a short circuit), and so you can get quite a bit of voltage drop across the meter when measuring micro amps. This leads to big errors in low voltage circuits.